# Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined mesmo com o import

Tags: javascript, html

Já aconteceu isso em outras paginas (do mesmo projeto) e consegui resolver baixando um arquivo e importando

```
<script src="../JavaScript/jquery-2.1.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Nas outras paginas funciona perfeitamente, mas nessa fica dando esse erro.

Comment: você se lembrou de importar o jquery antes das outras tags scripts ?

Comment: Provavelmente o erro está acontecendo pois você está utilizando caminhos relativos. Por isso, tente importar o jQuery de forma absoluta. Por exemplo: `http://localhost/JavaScript/jquery-2.1.3.min.js`.